# Django funcion views, creating a company with user associated

Tags: django, view

So, i have this problem when im trying to create my "company", when i didnt have user authentication the view worked just fine. Now i've added django allauth, and this screen appears to me:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FgZUy.png)

So i will leave here my model and my view to create the company
Im just a begginner so sry for my bad explanation

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4OfFa.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MI2xV.png)

The URLS : https://prnt.sc/K-lKvmfuQtvR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the problem is with the way your url is setup. Do you have a screenshot of the urls.py as well so we can see how you setup your url mapping. (OP added this screenshot: [prnt.sc/K-lKvmfuQtvR](https://prnt.sc/K-lKvmfuQtvR))

Your `companies/<pk>/` endpoint is catching your "create_company" value and storing it as a variable. Try moving your `companies/create_company` path above your `companies/<pk>/` like so

```
path('companies/', listing_companies),
path('companies/create_company/', company_create),
path('companies/<pk>', retrieve_companies),
path('companies/<pk>/update/', company_update),
path('companies/<pk>/delete/', company_delete),
```

Alternatively rename `companies/create_company/` to `create_company/` like so

```
path('companies/', listing_companies),
path('companies/<pk>', retrieve_companies),
path('create_company/', company_create),
path('companies/<pk>/update/', company_update),
path('companies/<pk>/delete/', company_delete),
```

The end goal in either case is simply to make sure your paths are not capturing your "create_company" and storing it as that  variable that it is passing along to your path's method.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/K-lKvmfuQtvR

Comment: sry, i should ive added in the post

Comment: No worries thanks for attaching the image. I've updated my original answer with more details